# I need help to create a Xpath XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I need navigate to eventos, I managed to get to the Body,I've tried a lot of different ways  but i have no idea how I can go to eventos

Here is the Xpath to get in Body  `//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body`

The full XML that i need to navigate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace xmlns:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace="http://opnet.com">pid=51867,requestid=514f6f1c3ce5d216f124779a80119db21dbad1c6d38cc9a9</X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:buscaEventosResponse xmlns:ns2="http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/">
      <return>
        <versao>2.0</versao>
        <qtd>1</qtd>
        <objeto>
          <numero>JS331400752BR</numero>
          <sigla>JS</sigla>
          <nome>REGISTRADO LÓGICO</nome>
          <categoria>REGISTRADO LÓGICO</categoria>
          <evento>
            <tipo>LDI</tipo>
            <status>01</status>
            <data>01/07/2016</data>
            <hora>17:08</hora>
            <descricao>Objeto aguardando retirada no endereço indicado</descricao>
            <detalhe>Para retirá-lo, é preciso informar o código do objeto.</detalhe>
            <local>AGF JOAO PAULINO</local>
            <codigo>37130976</codigo>
            <cidade>Alfenas</cidade>
            <uf>MG</uf>
            <endereco>
              <codigo>290998</codigo>
              <cep>37130000</cep>
              <logradouro>R PEDRO SILVEIRA, 65</logradouro>
              <localidade>Alfenas</localidade>
              <uf>MG</uf>
              <bairro>Centro</bairro>
            </endereco>
          </evento>
          <evento>
            <tipo>BDI</tipo>
            <status>04</status>
            <data>22/06/2016</data>
            <hora>10:52</hora>
            <descricao>A entrega não pode ser efetuada - Cliente recusou-se a receber</descricao>
            <detalhe>Objeto será devolvido ao remetente</detalhe>
            <recebedor>
            </recebedor>
            <documento>
            </documento>
            <comentario>?</comentario>
            <local>AC ULIANOPOLIS</local>
            <codigo>68632970</codigo>
            <cidade>Ulianopolis</cidade>
            <uf>PA</uf>
          </evento>
            <tipo>PO</tipo>
            <status>01</status>
            <data>03/06/2016</data>
            <hora>16:56</hora>
            <descricao>Objeto postado</descricao>
            <local>AGF AFRANIO RODRIGUES</local>
            <codigo>38400991</codigo>
            <cidade>Uberlandia</cidade>
            <uf>MG</uf>
          </evento>
        </objeto>
      </return>
    </ns2:buscaEventosResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

`//*[local-name()='evento']`

The way it works is xpath searches for all nodes with name 'evento' recursively but at the same time remain agnostic of the namespace.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.